# Can Aerospike return only specified bins?

Tags: aerospike

Simply, how can I get only specified bins out of a record?

A record has the bins:

```
(data1, data2 ...)
```

I query the record by it's **primary key** but want to specify I only want **data1** bin to be returned so I don't have to send a massive record but only the parts I want!

so aerospike result would be something like this:

```
id: (data1)
```

**This is not a secondary index query!**

Comment: What language are you developing in? Also, you don't need a secondary index to do single record operations. In fact, you don't want it, if that's how you're using Aerospike.

Comment: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/usage/kvs/read.html#projecting-the-bins-of-a-record
It is called select! Found it finally

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in every language client there's a way to limit a `get` to just the bins you want.
You probably should 'read the manual'. In the case of Python, see https://aerospike-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/usage/kvs/read.html#projecting-the-bins-of-a-record

Comment: Right, it says you can project, the academic term  for selecting a column from a row in a database. But really, you should be reading https://aerospike-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We can get specified bins from set using java client

**client.get(policy, key, "bin1","bin2");**

using query statement like below

**statement.setBinNames("bin1","bin2","bin3");**

Answer (score 0):

```
$ aql
aql> select data1 from test.testset where pk="rec1"
```

Comment: User probably wants to select bins from their application, AQL shouldn't be used from the application.